# C++ thread safe doubly linked list

Tags: c++, windows, data-structures

I need the above data structure for an application I'm writing.  I wondered if there is a library that already implements it or if I have to write it myself?

I don't really want to reinvent the wheel if it is not necessary.

I need this structure to be able to add and remove items using multiple threads without having to lock up the whole structure while doing so.

Comment: Can you write what operations do you really require from the structure? Perhaps you do not really need a double linked list and other structure might work as well?

Comment: How thread safe do you want it? You want to write to arbitrary positions from arbitrary threads?

Comment: How fast do you require the add and remove to be? At first sight it seems to be a hash table might work for you. Scalable thread safe hash tables are common - just search for some.

Comment: I want to add/remove items without needing to lock the entire list. So lock the item to be removed/added and off course the prev and next items.

Comment: This datastructure might contain quite a lot of items at any time, so it should be fast.  This is a server application, with many clients.

Comment: What criterion will be used for removal? Do you need to remove the items based on the item, or is "remove as processed" OK? If you want just to remove the items you have processed, single linked list is all you need.

Comment: Remove items as taken for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to a related research: [Is a lock (wait) free doubly linked list possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849786/is-a-lock-wait-free-doubly-linked-list-possible/849837#849837)

As you are not requesting a lock-free container, I am not marking this as an exact duplicate.

Note: while the interface and performance characteristics looks like a double linked list, internally those structures are very complex, based on hash tables or other structures. There is nothing which would a a double linked list internally and would be lock free at the same time. I do not remember seeing a proof, but I think this is not possible.

---

Based on your additional information, I think you do not need a double linked list at all. You can use the [Windows API single linked list instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686962%28VS.85%29.aspx). To add use InterlockedPushEntrySList, to remove for processing use InterlockedPopEntrySList.

Comment: Yes! InterlockedSLists are extremely fast and are already built-in to the OS

Answer (score 5):

There might be, but I think this was one of the lessons learned early in Java - data synchronicity is usually not at the container's member function level, but one step above.  You should be using synchronisation objects before accessing a non-thread-safe list instead.

Consider:

```
ThreadSafeQueue tsq;
tsq.push_back(...); // add lots of data

...

// Find the first element that returns true for search_criteria(elem);
auto iter = tsq.find_if(search_criteria); 
// (1)                                  
if(iter != tsq.end()) // (2)
{
    tsq.erase(iter);
}
```

In this thread-safe queue, there are still two "gaps" where the queue can be changed by another thread.  And, indeed, your iterator may be invalidated by those changes.  Now compare:

```
Queue q;
q.push_back(...); // add lots of data

...

// Create some lock around a pre-existing mutex.
Lock lock(q_mutex);
// Find the first element that returns true for search_criteria(elem);
auto iter = q.find_if(search_criteria); 

if(iter != q.end())
{
    q.erase(iter);
}
// lock unlocks as it goes out of scope.
```

Here, because the lock has a larger granularity, it is possible to ensure consistency across the written algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

would this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html work?

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of papers on writing lock free queues using assembly/compiler intrinsics to perform atomic operations but it's really difficult to get it working.

So if you can use locks, maybe use something like this: [Concurrent FIFO Queue with Boost](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html)